# upper bound on partial sums of Dirichlet character

Tags: number-theory

Let $\chi$ be a non-principal character modulo k. Then for two integers $m,n$ with $m<n$, prove that
$$\left|\sum_{j=m}^n \chi(j)\right|\leq \frac{1}{2}\phi(k)$$
It's easy to prove the trivial estimate which is $\phi(k)$. Also, I am able to prove the above estimate in case of odd characters. I don't how to prove it for even characters.

Answer (score 1):

The function $\sum_{j=m}^x \chi(j)$ is a periodic function of $x$; it is a step function, with steps that are complex numbers of modulus $1$, and it has $\phi(k)$ steps per period. So it can't get above $\phi(k)/2$ in modulus before half the steps have gone by; and if it got above $\phi(k)/2$ afterwards, how would it get back down to $0$ by the end of the period?

Comment: Can you explain a little more? It's clear that since half of the relatively prime integers are less than k/2, till k/2 it can go maximum to \phi(k)/2 but I didn't get your argument after that. I can see that in case of odd characters the values in the one half cancels the values in the other half and ultimately you are in just one half but this is not the same case with even characters as the sum up to give a factor of 2. Thanks.

Comment: For an even character, you must actually have $0 = \sum_{j=1}^{k} \chi(j) = 2 \sum_{j=1}^{k/2} \chi(j)$, so the sum at the halfway point actually equals $0$. But this symmetry only happens at $m=0$ anyway, so it doesn't solve the general problem (even for odd characters). If $x-m > k/2$, use the fact that $\sum_{j=m}^x \chi(j) + \sum_{j=x+1}^{m+k-1} \chi(j) = 0$ to get the required bound.