# Bounding $\sum_{p\leq x} \chi(p )$ for non-principal character $\chi$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Suppose $\chi$ is a non-principal Dirichlet character mod $k$. Let $A(x)=\sum_{n\leq x} \chi(n)$. Since $\sum_{n\leq k} \chi(n)=0$, we easily get the bound $|A(x)|\leq \varphi(k)$ where $\varphi$ is the Euler totient function.

Now let's define $B(x)=\sum_{p\leq x} \chi(p )$ where the sum extends over primes $p\leq x$. What kind of upper bounds do we have on $|B(x)|$? I am looking for any kind of big Oh estimates.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67796/sums-of-dirichlet-characters-over-prime-numbers-part-2 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514329/upper-bound-on-partial-sums-of-dirichlet-character.

Comment: [Siegel Walfisz Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siegel%E2%80%93Walfisz_theorem) implies that $O(x\exp(-c\sqrt{\log x}))$ is possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is known that for $x$ large and if $\chi$ is primitive with modulo $k > 2$, then
$$B(x) \ll k^{1/2} x (\log x)^{-A}$$
for any $A > 0$. The implied constant, which is ineffective, depends only on $A$.

**Ref** H. Iwaniec and E. Kowalski, *Analytic Number Theory*, AMS 53, 2004, page 124.